# 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am following the data generator tutorial in Keras:

https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

In __data_generation function they create a empty numpy array X. However, when I do that I get the following error:

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The dimension for my input is (1,7000,208) and (1,7000). However when I try to make numpy array I get the error I've mentioned before. This is what I do:

```py
dim_snp = (1,7000,208)
dim_pos = (1,7000)

X_snp = np.empty([1,dim_snp,1])
X_pos = np.empty((1,dim_pos))
```

Can someone explain why I get that error?

Comment: The argument for `np.empty` is supposed to a tuple of numbers.  What is `(1, dim_pos)`?

Comment: It doesn't even go to that line. The error comes for X_snp? And in the tutorial dim was 32,32,32

Comment: Can't you apply my comment to the `X_snp` line?

Comment: it is the size of my numpy array. It's a matrix of size 7000 x 208

Comment: I didn't ask what `(1, dim_pos)` was meant to be!  I wanted you to check what it actually is, and determine whether it's right to job.

Comment: So, I have saved my numpy arrays as npy files. I don't want to read the data all at once into the memory because it's a lot so I was thinking of reading batch of data everytime. And so I am making numpy array that can store batches of those arrays. So 1 is simply the batch size which I will obviously change in my final code. For now I was just checking if I could store each batch in 'X'. dim_pos is the dimension of my input.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [23]: dim_snp = (1,7000,208)                                                 
In [24]: (1, dim_snp, 1)                                                        
Out[24]: (1, (1, 7000, 208), 1)

In [25]: np.zeros((1, dim_snp, 1))                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-10a1e967522d> in <module>
----> 1 np.zeros((1, dim_snp, 1))

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In [26]: np.zeros((1, 1, 700, 208, 1)).shape                                    
Out[26]: (1, 1, 700, 208, 1)
```